# ng-repeat script is been commented while executing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is My code where I am using the rootProvider template

```
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="obj in myArray">{{obj.com_name}}</li> 
</ul>
```

My Controller is :

```
    routingApp.controller('Controller-Param', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    var aid = $routeParams.id;
$scope.myArray = "[{"company_id":"1","com_name":"jcb","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"},{"company_id":"2","com_name":"komatsu","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"}]
";

});
```

Here is the comment script

```
<div ng-view=""><ul class="ng-scope">
    <!-- ngRepeat: obj in myArray -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the quotes "" around your JSON array. Otherwise it will be taken as a string, so you are seeing an empty div

**DEMO**

```js
var routingApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

routingApp.controller('Controller-Param', function($scope) {
$scope.myArray = [{"company_id":"1","com_name":"jcb","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"},{"company_id":"2","com_name":"komatsu","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"}];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Controller-Param">
<ul >
    <li ng-repeat="obj in myArray">{{obj.com_name}}</li> 
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.myArray = [{"company_id":"1","com_name":"jcb","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"},{"company_id":"2","com_name":"komatsu","val_equ_id":"1","created_on":"2018-03-24 13:00:43"}];
```

Replace this line in your code